# Encoding an audio sample at specific timings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am using Pydub in Python to take a two second sample mp3 file and repeat this at multiple timings to create a single minute long file. I wish to repeat this functionality in Javascript, but am unsure if this is possible?

Is it possible to load a sample mp3 file, repeat this at millisecond timings (taken from an existing array of timings), write these to a single mp3 and then export to the desktop?

Pydub enables easy audio manipulation such as this in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebAudio's [decodeAudioData](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-baseaudiocontext-decodeaudiodata) to convert the mp3 into an array of samples.  Then you can use Javascript to arrange that array of samples in any way want.

Once you have this final array, you can use [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) to encode the array of samples into a compressed audio file.  (Although I don't think anyone supports mp3 with MediaRecorder.  You'll have to deal with that in a different way or use some other library to convert to mp3.)

Also, perhaps the [Beautiful Audio Editor](https://beautifulaudioeditor.appspot.com) might be useful too.  (There are other editors out there.)

Comment: I am unsure how I could position the sample as specific timings with this method? Pydub enables this via simply looping through an array of milliseconds and writing the sample file within the loop.

Comment: I don't know anything about Pydub, so I can't help with that.  but you have the raw audio data now, so you can manipulate it as you like.  From your description, maybe just copy the short array into the appropriate places into a new array, where you've converted milliseconds to frame number (frame = time * sampleRate).